# Getting Actual Value of a Property using PropertyInfo Class

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I am using the PropertyInfo method to get the size of an attachment I am uploading using the fyneworks jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin. It all works fine, however I need to get the real-value of my property. I set the file size of the attachment using the code below:

```
PropertyInfo sizeProperty = aType.GetProperty("Size");
sizeProperty.SetValue(attachmentItem, fileData.Length, null);
```

For simplicity say I want to write to the console:

```
Console.WriteLine("FILE SIZE: " + sizeProperty.ToString());
```

The above code returns this: **FILE SIZE: System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] Size.**
Which is not really useful.

Side note- although not ideal I have to use reflection as I am restrained by what has been given to me. Ideally I would like to access the properties directly, but I am not able to.

Comment: Why are you using reflection instead of just accessing the properties?

Comment: If it has `SetValue` then it might also have `G...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PropertyInfo` represents attributes and metadata of a property in regards to a type, not an instance. When you want to use it in relation to an instance, you have to use [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee433930.aspx) or [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436193.aspx)

In your case, `GetValue` will give you the correct size if you pass it the instance, but then @mason question is really interesting: why not access the property of the instance directly?